# General solution of $y''-2xy'+2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the general solution of the differential equation $$y''-2xy'+2y=0.$$ An obvious solution is $y(x)=ax$ but I am unable to find another solution. Any hint as to how to proceed or which kind of method to apply is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: there is a standard method called variation of parameters. Take $y=xg(x)$ (obtained by replacing the constant in your first solution by a function). Plug this into the ODE and put $h=g'$. You will get a first order ODE for $h$. You should now be able to complete the answer. Note: please see comment below by LutzL.

Comment: I arrive at $xh'+(2-2x^2)h=0$. The only method I can think of to solve this would be separation of variables. However, I would need to divide by $x$ and as the solution $y$ should be $y:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ this would be a problem.

Comment: The solution is $h(x)=x^{2}e^{-x^{2}}$ valid for all $x$. Don't worry too much about dividing by $0$. Once you get a  solution you can go back and verify that it solves the given ODE. @Analysis801

Comment: [Variation of parameters/constants, also  Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) is a different method to get particular/inhomogeneous solutions of linear ODE. What you are doing is called [reduction of order, sometimes method of d’Alembert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order).

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the comment. I was not sure of the name but the argument works.

Answer (score 2):

Making $z = x y$ we obtain

$$
z''-\frac{2(x^2-1)}{x}z' = 0
$$

now making $v = z'$

$$
v'-\frac{2(x^2-1)}{x}v = 0
$$

which is separable.